# React: VariableDeclarator ASTNodes are not handled by markPropTypesAsUsed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently built my React App (scaffolded using Create React App, using `yarn build`) using our CI server and got build error shown below:

```
Error: VariableDeclarator ASTNodes are not handled by markPropTypesAsUsed      
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  }
```

Comment: Same problem :/

Comment: Can you share more details, for example some sample code that triggers the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can downgrade "eslint-plugin-react" to 7.13.0 version to wait for fix in 7.14.0. It works for me.

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue with the newest version of `eslint-plugin-react` (version `7.14.0`) . People are already working on a fix and this will probably be solved soon in a newer version. The code is already merged. For more you can check: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2319

<s>For now as a work-around you can downgrade the eslint-plugin-react to `7.13.0` in order to temporary solve your problem till this is fixed.</s>

**Last Update:** The issue is now fixed by releasing the version `7.14.1` with just this fix. If you are getting this error just update to the latest version and the issue and make sure that you have the version `7.14.1` or later and this will be solved.